# Eclipse's equivalent of IntelliJ's Ctrl+P

Tags: eclipse

In IntelliJ, when your cursor is inside a method, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to view the parameters of the method.

What's the equivalent shortcut in Eclipse?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this command list](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-jdk-ide-tutorials/19-list-shortcuts-key-eclipse.html), it's possible to show the list of parameter types for a method using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>SPace</kbd>. Also, you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut to show a list of all shortcuts in Eclipse.

Comment: Luckily Ctrl + Shift + Space also applies to Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ctrl + Shift + Space to view the parameters of methods in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift + Space should work, Ctrl + P tries to print actually...